# How to reject specific string in a comment board

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a comment board using the script below, I want to make it so that if a user enters the handle then it stops the comment from being posted. But I am unsure how to do it as I am relatively new to javascript. Do I need some sort of if statement? specifically I need the handle of "hacker" to be rejected but I am not sure how to formulate the expression. Is this the correct implementation of an if statement to reject the string "hacker"

HTML

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Comment section</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="code.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="alert"> Your message has been sent</div>
    <h1> Spartak Swinford FC - Comment Section</h1>
    <form id=contactform" action="#"
          <fieldset>
              <legend>Give us your thoughts on the team!</legend>
              <span>Email : </span><input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
              <span>Handle: </span><input type="text" id="handle" placeholder="Handle"><br>
              <span style="position: absolute;"></span>
              <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="50" rows="8">Enter your message...</textarea>
              <br>
              <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="sendMessage()">Post</button>
              <div id="clientSideContent"></div>
          </fieldset>
    </form>
<h1>Comments</h1>
<div id="comments"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
var array = [];

function sendMessage() {

let emailjs = email.value;
email.value = ""

let handlejs = handle.value;
handle.value = ""

let messagejs = message.value;
message.value = ""

    let userobject= {emailjs, handlejs, messagejs}

    array.push(userobject);

if (handle.value) == ("hacker")
    print(""):
else
        console.log(array)
    let sHTML = "<table class=\"table table-striped\">\n" +
        "  <thead>\n" +
        "    <tr>\n" +
        "      <th scope=\"col\">Email</th>\n" +
        "      <th scope=\"col\">Handle</th>\n" +
        "      <th scope=\"col\">Message</th>\n"
        "    </tr>\n" +
        "  </thead>\n" +
        "  <tbody>\n";
    for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        sHTML += "<tr><td>" + array[i].emailjs + "</td><td>" + array[i].handlejs +"</td><td>" + array[i].messagejs + "</td></tr>";
    }
    sHTML += "</tbody></table><br>";
    console.log(sHTML);
    comments.innerHTML = sHTML;
}
```

Comment: If you just want to reject the _exact_ handle `hacker`, then you don't need an expression, you only need a simple comparison.

Comment: So could I write something along the lines of, if handle.js == "hacker", print(""), else

Comment: As long as you use correct if statement syntax (and the _correct_ variable name) ... Yes.

Comment: That is perfect, thanks a million for the help, I have added a statement there but I don't think I have done it correctly, apologies I am very new to coding so I struggle to differentiate between a comparison and an expression

Comment: Not sure what `print` is supposed to be, and the `:` behind it makes little sense either. If you simply want to do _nothing_, when your condition is met - then don't use if/else, but just an if with the negated condition. And check on the _right_ variable - `handle.value` is just an empty string, you _assigned_ that a couple of lines before. `if (handlejs !== 'hacker') { /* do stuff */ }`